# Copying parquet data from s3 to dynamodb using glue job

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

I am trying to copy parquet data in s3 to dynamodb using glue job (spark). The parquet data in s3 is created using glue job from dynamodb. I am getting below error at the last step of the glue job for importing from s3 into DynamoDB.

```
{"service":"AWSGlue","statusCode":400,"errorCode":"InvalidInputException","requestId":"7cf6c14c-2c3b-11ea-878b-8990bca54d25","errorMessage":"No enum constant com.amazonaws.services.glue.FileFormat.DYNAMODB","type":"AwsServiceError"}
```

Comment: How do you write to DynamoDB? Can you share your Glue script?

Comment: Looks like glue does not support importing into dynamodb, here is the link -- ```AWS Glue does not currently support writing to Amazon DynamoDB.``` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-dynamodb. Trying to do with spark, will share update once done.